# Newest iTunes doesn't recognize iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, ios, password, restart

I have an iPhone 6s that I want to reset since we don't know the passcode. I'm using Windows 10, but I can get access to a Mac if that would help. The iPhone connects successfully to the iTunes version linked in [this reset article](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204306), but it immediately tells me to update to the latest iTunes if I want to update or restore the phone.

However, the newest version of iTunes downloaded from the Microsoft Store doesn't connect to this phone at all, and a message pops up that the USB device isn't recognized.

I don't get the [Erase iPhone](https://www.tomsguide.com/how-to/how-to-reset-a-locked-iphone-without-a-computer) shown on Tom's guide here, so the phone must have a slightly older iOS installed. I've found paid software online that alleged unlocks iPhones but I'm not sure if they're reliable, malware, etc. I have the .ipsw file that I can use to restore the phone but not sure what I can do with it.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this situation?

Comment: Does this help?  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212542

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I managed to figure out how to get it working. See posted answer.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to get this working. What I ended up doing is installing the old version, plugging in the phone and making sure it registered the device, then I installed the new version while the old version was still installed (previously I had uninstalled the old version). This triggers Apple's upgrade process which seems to preserve the drivers.

Comment: New/old version of iTunes?  You might want to specify that.

Comment: Specify what? My original post linked directly to the old version, and the new version is whatever version is in the Microsoft store.

Comment: Imagine someone coming to this answer in 2 years time when the 'new version is whatever version is in the Microsoft store' has moved on a few revisions. How is anyone to know whether your original issue was related to a specific version and solved only by a specific newer version? In addition the linked Apple KB article does not reference a specific iTunes version either (Apple update answers too). Remember that your answer is not just relevant to you and your original question.